# Why aren't all vector bundles local systems?

Tags: differential-geometry, algebraic-topology, vector-bundles

A local system is a bundle with locally constant sheaf of sections. I have seen several equivalent characterizations (bundles acted upon nicely by the fundamental group of the base, bundles admitting flat connections, etc), and from this I can construct examples of vector bundles that are provably not local systems (e.g. the tangent bundle of a sphere).

On the other hand, as far as I can tell, a local trivialization of a vector bundle over a contractible neighborhood should force the restriction of the sheaf of sections to be constant over the same neighborhood. But this would seem to imply that *all* bundles correspond to local systems.

Can anyone help me resolve this apparent contradiction?

Comment: Why does a local trivialization of a vector bundle make the restriction of the sheaf of sections constant?

Comment: I am probably wrong about this, but my logic is as follows: I know that the sheaf of sections of a trivial bundle is constant; I also know that the restriction of the sheaf of sections is the sheaf of sections of the restriction; hence the restriction of the sheaf of sections to a chart supporting a trivialization is constant.

Comment: "I know that the sheaf of sections of a trivial bundle is constant" This isn't true.  I'll elaborate in an answer in a minute.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

> On the other hand, as far as I can tell, a local trivialization of a vector bundle over a contractible neighborhood should force the restriction of the sheaf of sections to be constant over the same neighborhood.

This isn't true at all.  When you talk about a vector bundle having a locally constant sheaf of sections, that locally constant sheaf isn't going to be the sheaf of *all* (continuous) sections of the vector bundle; rather, it is a very special subsheaf of the sheaf of all sections.  For instance, if you have the trivial line bundle $X\times \mathbb{R}$ over a space $X$, the sheaf of continuous sections gives you all continuous real-valued functions, while the locally constant sheaf corresponding to the trivial local system consists of only the locally constant real-valued functions.  Most spaces have plenty of continuous real-valued functions on them that are not locally constant, so these two sheaves are quite different.

It is true that given a trivialization of a vector bundle, there is a canonical way to turn the vector bundle into a local system (namely, take the locally constant $\mathbb{R}^n$-valued functions).  But different trivializations of the same bundle will give rise to different local systems in this way, and so if you have a general vector bundle, it might not be possible to choose local trivializations which give rise to compatible local systems and thus a global local system.

Answer (score 6):

Given a vector bundle, there is no meaningful notion of locally constant sections of it without extra data. You can define what "locally constant" means with respect to a particular local trivialization, but this notion depends on the choice of local trivialization, and it generally won't be possible to patch local trivializations together along *locally constant* transition maps, which is what you'd need for "locally constant" to be well-defined globally.

For example, complex line bundles on, say, a smooth manifold are classified by their first Chern classes $c_1 \in H^1(X, \mathbb{Z})$. Among these, the ones which can be made locally constant (equivalently, the ones that can be equipped with [flat connections](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Connection_(vector_bundle))) have the property that $c_1$ is torsion.